# Get the position behind an object (locally) ? - Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, coordinates, unityscript

I ran into a problem while making my complex(ish) camera behaviour (using Javascript). The problem that i have run to is that i am not able to get the position behind my player. Please don't tell me to use Vector3.back etc.. , because i want the position locally, to support turning. It won't work if the camera is always set to that position, cos i have a cool movement system in place.

I tried a number of approaches, and confused myself with the math. I also tried complex addition and subtraction. None of them worked at all.

I guess i am probably missing something quite simple, like a way to get into local coordinates etc.. ( or maybe a few math functions )

thanks in advance
-Etaash

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the [forward](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-forward.html) vector of any transform, and if you negate that it is the backward vector. So on a script attached to the player you would have:

```
Vector3 backward = -transform.forward;
```

So to get a position, you could do something like this:

```
Vector3 pos = transform.position + (backward * dist); // where dist is a float to scale how far away from the position you want it
```